# How to get complex JSON from URL?

Tags: android, arrays, json

My json is like this

```
{
    "results": [{
        "syllabus": "CBSE",
        "grade": "5",
        "subject": "Kannada",
        "topic": "Grammar Level 1",
        "id": 28
    }]
}
```

Using Volley

```
         JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(urlJsonArry,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                    try {
                        // Parsing json array response
                        // loop through each json object
                        jsonResponse = "";
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject person = (JSONObject) response
                                    .get(i);

                            System.out.println(person.toString());





                            String syllabus = person.getString("syllabus");
                            String grade= person.getString("grade");
                            jsonResponse += "Name: " + syllabus + "\n\n";
                            jsonResponse += "Email: " + grade + "\n\n";


                        }
```

Comment: replace `new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {` with `new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {` as response is `JSONObject`

Comment: That's "complex" JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Json have an object and then array.. try like this

```
JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(urlJsonArry,

            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

              try {
          JSONOArray array = response.getJSONArray("results") 
                    // Parsing json array response
                    // loop through each json object
                    jsonResponse = "";
                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject person = (JSONObject) array
                                .get(i);

                        System.out.println(person.toString());

                        String syllabus = person.getString("syllabus");
                        String grade= person.getString("grade");
                        jsonResponse += "Name: " + syllabus + "\n\n";
                        jsonResponse += "Email: " + grade + "\n\n";


                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            if (!result.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {

            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result); //result is what you get responce
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.optJSONArray("results");
                if (jsonArray != null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObjects = jsonArray.optJSONObject(i);
                        String syllabus = jsonObjects.optString("syllabus");
                        Int grade = jsonObjects.optInt("grade");
                        String subject = jsonObjects.optString("subject");
                        String topic = jsonObjects.optString("topic");
                        Int id = jsonObjects.optInt("id");                                                    
                    }
                    } else {
                    Log.e("", "error parse json", "--->" + e.getMessage());
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("", "error parse json", "--->" + e.getMessage());
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("", "error parse json", "--->" + e.getMessage());
        }
```

Comment: Could you try sticking with Volley since that is what OP is using?

Comment: I thing question is of json parsing as @Shwetabh Singh is getting responce

Comment: I understand the problem, but a `JsonObjectRequest` would hopefully be used instead of a `JsonArrayRequest`, and so the `new JSONObject(result)` would only really be necessary for a `StringRequest`. Also, using `return` isn't possible in a Volley call